# como saltar de un select2 a un input con la tecla enter y de un input a un select2

Tags: javascript, html5

hola por favor necesito saltar con la tecla enter de un input a un select2 y también de un select2 a un input y cuando haga enter en el boton me salte otra vez al select2 de detalleingreso_id pero no salta solo se queda ahi, ya intente de muchas maneras pero no logro hacerlo

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<body>

</head>

<body>
<input type="number" tabindex="1" class="focusNext form-control " name="cantidad" id="cantidad" placeholder="CANTIDAD"> 

<select name="detalleingreso_id" id="detalleingreso_id" tabindex="2" class=" form-control select2">
           <option value="hola1">1</option>
           <option value="hola1">2</option>                            
</select>
<input type="text" tabindex="3" class="focusNext form-control " name="responsable" id="reponsable" placeholder="Ingrese nombre" required="true"> 
                                
<input type="number" tabindex="4" class="focusNext form-control " name="cant2" id="cant2" placeholder="CANTIDAD">   
<button tabindex="4" class="focusNext btn btn-primary" type="button" id="bt_add" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> AGREGAR A CARRITO</button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.select2').select2();

    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) 
        {
          if (evt.key !== 'Enter' ) {
            return ;
          }
          
          let element = evt.target;
  
          if (!element.classList.contains('focusNext')) {
            return ;
          }

          let tabIndex = element.tabIndex + 1;
          var next = document.querySelector('[tabindex="'+tabIndex+'"]');

          if (next) {
            next.focus();
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

hola por favor necesito saltar con la tecla enter de un input a un select2 y tambien de un select2 a un input y cuando haga enter en el boton me salte otra vez al select de detalleingreso_id pero no salta solo se queda ahi, ya intente de muchas maneras pero no logro hacerlo

Comment: salta entre input pero cuando salta a un select2 se queda ahi

Comment: Si intentas hacer eso en un formulario el **Enter** hará que se envié el formulario, esto es básico en cualquier formulario, lo que buscas en un `focus()` al siguiente campo?

Comment: si pero no envia el formulario, salta de un campo a otro entre inputs, pero al saltar de un select2 a un input ya no salta se queda en el select2

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, acomodé un poco tu HTML porque parece que la librería de select2 requiere jQuery primero.

Lo que se debe hacer es guardar en una variable los campos en nuestra pantalla, en otra variable la posición del campo que actualmente tiene el foco, luego cuando se presione Enter aumentar esta posición para así asignar el foco en el campo siguiente.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Consultamos los campos en nuestra pantalla
  let campos = $('input, select');

  // Indice del campo que actualmente tiene el foco
  let indiceCampoConFoco = 0;

  // Por defecto ponemos el foco en el primer campo
  campos[indiceCampoConFoco].focus();

  $(document).keydown((event) => {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
      // Se ha presionado la tecla Enter

      // Aumentamos el indice del campo a enfocar
      if (indiceCampoConFoco < (campos.length - 1)) {
        indiceCampoConFoco++;
      } else {
        indiceCampoConFoco = 0;
      }

      // Enfocar en el campo según el indice actual
      campos[indiceCampoConFoco].focus();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">

</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" tabindex="1" class="focusNext form-control " name="cantidad" id="cantidad" placeholder="CANTIDAD">

  <select name="detalleingreso_id" id="detalleingreso_id" tabindex="2" class=" form-control select2">
    <option value="hola1">1</option>
    <option value="hola1">2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" tabindex="3" class="focusNext form-control " name="responsable" id="reponsable" placeholder="Ingrese nombre" required="true">

  <input type="number" tabindex="4" class="focusNext form-control " name="cant2" id="cant2" placeholder="CANTIDAD">
  <button tabindex="4" class="focusNext btn btn-primary" type="button" id="bt_add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            AGREGAR A CARRITO</button>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero que te sirva.

*Nota: Ten cuidado si vas a crear un formulario con la etiqueta , pues la acción predeterminada al presionar Enter es hacer un post al servidor, entonces tendrás que controlar el evento submit.*

Comment: muchas gracias!!!  por tu ayuda evite el submit en el form al presionar enter, y aumente un input oculto para que no haga el salto del select2 al mismo tiempo que el input :)

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido, por favor marcar la pregunta como resuelta. ;)